# Copy Multiple Items To Clipboard

Tags: java, copy, clipboard

For admin purposes on one of my sites for me alone using IE - I use software (xNeat Clipboard Manager) that allows me to access my Clipboard History. I have PHP pages that are populated from MySql. I want to be able to click a record and send various pieces of info from that record to my Clipboard so that I can access each one individually via the history.

Using Java I am tring to send multiple items to the clipboard one at a time in order to do this. I can get it to work as long as I use an Alert after each clipboard copy - but if I drop the Alert then only the last incident goes to the clipboard. Obviously I do not want to have to click ok in an alert box ten times if it can be avoided so I am looking for a method to make this work without the alert box.

Below is a redacted version of what is working with the alert box - redacted in the sense that it is only three items instead of ten.

```
function copy_clip(id,author,copyright) 
{    window.clipboardData.setData('text',copyright);
     alert(copyright);
     window.clipboardData.setData('text',author);
     alert(author);
     window.clipboardData.setData('text',id);
}
```

No need for an alert on the last one - only the ones that I want to copy before the last one requires the alert.

So how could I accomplish this without the alert and thus only require a single click in order to populate the clipboard and its history?

Thanks